# Can't create array of views conforming to same protocol?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I created a protocol which conforms to `View` then I created 2 `structs` that conform to the same protocl, I call them `v1` and `v2`.

In my main array I created an array which takes a value of type `T` which conforms to protocol `viewTest`. So far everything is fine, problem is when I call `testView`. For example, in the preview I am calling `testView` and passing it `v1` and `v2` which are of the same type I suppose since both are conforming to same parent and the array is of type `parent`; However, the app keeps crashing with the error `Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report` if I only pass array of same type say `v1` then everything works. I don't know what is going on or is this a bug? I am running `Version 12.1 (12A7403)`

Here is a reproducible code

```
import SwiftUI
protocol viewTest: View {
    var name: String {get set}
}

struct v1: viewTest {
    var name: String = "v1"
    var body: some View {
        Text("Name: \(name)")
    }
}

struct v2: viewTest {
    var name: String = "v2"
    var body: some View {
        Text("2nd view name: \(name)")
    }
}


struct testView<T: viewTest>: View{
    @State var arr: [T]
    @State private var index: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if(index >= 0) {
                self.arr[index]
                
                Button("Next", action: {
                    if(index < arr.count-1) {
                        index += 1
                    }
                })
            } else {
                Text("no views")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct testView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        testView(arr: [
            v1(),
            v2()   // Everything works after commenting out this line or changing it to `v1`
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: "v1 and v2 which are of the same type I suppose since both are conforming to same parent and the array is of type parent" - this isn't correct v1 and v2 are different types, they just confirm to the same protocol. A protocol is not a superclass.

Comment: That's what I thought as well but my argument was that I am not explicitly defining the type of T, all I am saying is that T must conform to `viewTest` which both `v1` and `v2` conform to. I have never specified the type of `T`. Does it automatically assign type based on the first element in the array? If so what would be an appropriate way to achieve my goal? without the use of `AnyView`

Comment: `View` is a protocol - it isn't a thing - it's a description that a type that conforms to it must satisfy. So you can't have an array of "Views". But you could have an array of specific type of a view, for example, an array of `v1`s. But, you shouldn't do this anyway. In SwiftUI, the data drives the view - so instead of an array of views, create an array of some data objects, and based on that, determine what view to show.

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest you stick with the Swift convention and Capitalize your types: `V1`, `V2`, `TestView`, `ViewTest`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense now. My goal is to make different fields that will be looped  through everytime the `next` button is pressed. However, each field will have its own view design and I wanted to make it reusable so in the future I can easily create a `field struct` that conforms to `field protocol` and then add it to the views array but it seems like it is not possible with at least the way I am thinking about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach - the main thing is that your protocol type should not contain generics.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

*Note: original style preserved intentionally*

```
protocol viewTest {                 // << here !!
    var name: String {get set}
    func getView() -> AnyView       // << here !!
}

extension viewTest where Self: View {
    func getView() -> AnyView {
        AnyView(self)
    }
}

struct v1: View, viewTest {
    var name: String = "v1"
    var body: some View {
        Text("Name: \(name)")
    }
}

struct v2: View, viewTest {
    var name: String = "v2"
    var body: some View {
        Text("2nd view name: \(name)")
    }
}

struct testView: View{
    var arr: [viewTest]                   // << here !!
    @State private var index: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if(index >= 0) {
                self.arr[index].getView()       // << here !!
                
                Button("Next", action: {
                    if(index < arr.count-1) {
                        index += 1
                    }
                })
            } else {
                Text("no views")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct testView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        testView(arr: [
            v1(),
            v2()
        ])
    }
}
```